# Do typical email spam filters measure "user engagement"?

Tags: gmail, bulk-email, spam-blocker

I recently received an email from my CRM (Keap by InfusionSoft) that informed me that there are new and time sensitive issues with email deliverability that I should address. The email implies that these are industry wide changes in practice, not a specific issue to me.

Among other things, it suggests that my "engagement", measured in "engagement days" is far too low and that

> Providers, like Gmail, want to ensure their users only receive interesting and relevant content in their inbox. If they notice their users are not engaging with your business’s emails, they’ll learn this behavior overtime and begin to send future emails to the junk folder.
> [Engagement Days - InfusionSoft help file](https://help.infusionsoft.com/help/engagement-days)

My specific numbers are that the "average days since last engagement has increased to 356.0 days." This number is not alarming to me. The nature of the business lends itself to recurring orders, but a year or two apart is not at all unusual. As such, we only send emails about every other month. The problem is that "The 'Engagement Days' metric measures the contacts that you have sent email marketing to in the last 30 days and the average amount of days since they have last engaged." This implies that 30 days or less between "engagements" is the ideal. I have no sensible business reason to get my customers to engage email content so frequently, yet it is perfectly sensible that they would engage only once a year or even less.

On one hand, I am absolutely incredulous that email clients like Gmail would even try to measure "engagement" in emails they have no financial interest in, but on the other hand, Google has been *singularly minded* to everyone else's detriment at times in the past.

Is this quoted behavior true? Does Gmail and other clients monitor engagement to inform and update spam filters? If it's true, what can I do to mitigate the possible harm? InfusionSoft suggests, basically, that I simply stop emailing a large portion of our list.

<sup>* For the specifics, our list is about 3,000 qualified entries, about 2,300 get sent the email when we do send, about 800 typically open it, around 100 will click, and about 80 bounceback. This looks like modest absolute numbers and respectable percentages to me.</sup>

Comment: I checked meta for this to be on topic, and decided [it is on topic based on this.](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1451/are-questions-about-email-hosting-on-topic)